# How do I find the sample standard deviation given the population standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, means

A large population has a mean of 150 and a standard deviation of 40. A sample of 100 observations is to be selected at random from the population. What is the standard deviation of the sample mean? The answer they give is 4 although that might be a rounded answer and I don't know how they got to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we sample from $X\sim N(150, 40^2)$ 100 times, then the sample mean is
$$\bar X = \frac{X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}}{100}.$$

Then 
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(\bar X) &= \text{Var}\left(\frac{X_1+\dotsb+X_{100}}{100}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{100^2}\text{Var}(X_1+\dotsb+X_{100})\\
&= \frac{1}{100^2}\cdot100\cdot\text{Var}(X_1) \\
&= \frac{40^2}{100}
\end{align*}
Hence
$$\text{SD}(\bar X) = \frac{40}{10} = 4.$$

If you use a box model, then
$$\text{SD}_{\text{avg}} = \frac{\text{SD}_{\text{box}}}{\sqrt{\text{#draws}}}.$$